# Multi-language support for Multiple Choice Lookup Table questions

Tags: commcare

Is it possible to specify multiple languages for the "Display Text Field" portion of a select option in a multiple choice lookup table question?  Note, I'm speaking specifically about the "Choice" definition, not the label for the question itself which does support multi-language already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute in the lookup table and a bit of a hack to get the current app locale ID to accomplish this.

There's a writeup on it here that covers it pretty well: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Using+Lookup+Tables+with+Multiple+Languages

Answer (score 1):

Not if your choices are specifically populated by the "organizations" (previously called "locations") functionality.

As currently implemented, you can set up the organizations table to support a particular language (esp a non-romanized script) in the display whilst also having romanized letters in the background (to support sorting, etc) but you can't dynamically switch between them.